# Youtube embedded video with overlapping title

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api, z-index

Out of nowhere the title on my youtube video is overlapping the share and more info buttons within the video header. If you hover over the video the title compresses correctly.

Fiddle with the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/QpckF/

Here is my code:

```
       <div class="interior-container">
            <h3 id="video-text">Why Book with Rail Europe?</h3>    
        <iframe frameborder="0" name="player" allowfullscreen="" id="player" title="YouTube video player" height="217" width="365" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/wV-S_MOusMI?controls=1&amp;showinfo=1&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http://www.raileurope.com"></iframe> 

              <div class="vid-arrows prevvid">
              <i class="vid-prev icon-video-left-arrow"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="vid-nav">
            <a target="player" data-text="Why Book with Rail Europe?" class="fader first active" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/wV-S_MOusMI?controls=1&amp;showinfo=1&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http://www.raileurope.com" id="default"></a>            
        <a target="player" data-text="Train Travel in Europe: Rail Pass vs. Tickets" class="fader first" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/rxlq8KirhNM?controls=1&amp;showinfo=1&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http://www.raileurope.com" id="default"></a>            
        <a target="player" data-text="Why Travel by Train in Europe?" class="fader first" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/pQ8DwmEg9wk?controls=1&amp;showinfo=1&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http://www.raileurope.com" id="default"></a>            
        </div> <!-- end vid-nav -->




        <div class="vid-arrows nextvid">
              <i class="vid-next icon-video-right-arrow"></i>
              </div>
        </div>        
    </div>​
```

Is this a problem with youtube or my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trial and error testing seems to indicate that this is just an interface bug in the Youtube Flash player -- it doesn't truncate the title properly until a mouseover event has been triggered.

A few other interface issues I discovered; it appears that when a video is less than 350px in width, those 'share' and 'more info' buttons aren't even rendered by the flash player, so the problem will only occur if it is more than 350px but less than needed to have the full title visible.

Also, if the video is less than 201 pixels in height, the control bar at the bottom won't auto appear (to save space); but when there is no control bar, then a mouseover cannot trigger the title to be concatenated until the video starts playing.

Minor annoyances, but ones that only come up in a few cases so  don't know how big of a priority they are. You could try reporting the bugs (or see if someone else already has).

Comment: Thanks for you help, looks like I will try to report the bug to youtube. This only started happening recently so they may have made a change to their API or something.

Comment: Youtube has fixed this bug by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  You can also add "showinfo=0" to the url and it won't show the title at all.